# Jsoup - getting src value of img from website

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

I am trying to get src value of the img element from a website using Jsoup. Everything else works correctly (getting other values from the image), but not getting src value of the element.

Code that I use:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").timeout(10000).get();
Element img = doc.getElementById("image_id");
String src = img.attr("src");
Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, src);
```

In return instead of URL I have strange logs.

On Samsung GT9515:

```
06-26 00:54:38.787  18713-18793/? V/My_App﹕ [ 06-26 00:54:38.787   272:  272 D/SurfaceFlinger ]
FPS : 59.92
```

And on Nexus 5 emulator:

```
06-25 19:01:08.027    2329-2373/? V/My_App﹕ [ 06-25 19:01:09.671  1596: 1596 I/auditd   ]
type=1400 audit(0.0:4eni avc:  denied  { 0x10 } for  cor_7"Binder_7" capability=36  scontext=u:r:system_servext=u tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=capability2
```

As I said before it works for other attributes of the image - width, height, abs:src...

Do you maybe know what could be the reason of the fault?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that I was not able to get src attribute of the image, because it was set after executing script on the site.
Solution to my problem is to parse parameters from the script and then build an URI that contains address with that parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements container = doc.select("div[class=\"image-banner\"]");
Element e = container.select("img").get(0);
System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
```